# How to Open Email Composer with Image attachment from JQuery Mobile\JavaScript

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Is it possible to open Email Composer window with image as attachment in mail composer window from **HTML Web Page**? I am trying to attach an image in Email Composer from a web page which will run in iOS Safari Browser.

I am able to open email composer using javascript code.

```
window.location.href = "mailto:email@email.com?subject=" Hello Subject"&body="Hello Body";
```

Let me know if anybody has suggestion\input.

Thanks

Suresh